# How to make a rotated, multiple-row label of a table vertically centered?

Tags: tables

How to exactly make a rotated, multiple-row label (i.e., `from`) of a table vertically centered?

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{array,multirow,graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|*5{c|}}
\cline{3-5}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{to}\\\cline{3-5}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{}                     & a & b & c\\\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{from}} & 1 & d & e & f\\\cline{2-5}
                                      & 2 & g & h & i\\\cline{2-5}
                                      & 3 & j & k & l\\\cline{2-5}
                                      & 4 & m & n & o\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @HarishKumar: Happy Chinese New Year! You can make it as your answer if you want.

Comment: Happy Chinese New Year to you too (Is it new year for them?). I added the answer. Hope it is useful :)

Comment: @HarishKumar: Yes, tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\rotatebox` macro takes a key value list as optional argument:

```
\rotatebox[key-val list]{angle}{text}
```

From `graphicx` documentation <sub>(David will be unhappy that I am using documentation ;)..)</sub>

[image]

Hence, we use `[origin=c]`:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{array,multirow,graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|*5{c|}}
\cline{3-5}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{to}\\\cline{3-5}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{}                     & a & b & c\\\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{from}} & 1 & d & e & f\\\cline{2-5}
                                      & 2 & g & h & i\\\cline{2-5}
                                      & 3 & j & k & l\\\cline{2-5}
                                      & 4 & m & n & o\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]