# How to make tables in which the text appears vertically?

Tags: tables

I want my table to appear as shown in the figure. Is it possible in Latex, and if it is how can it be done?[image: Figure shows that the text is written vertically in the table.]

Comment: Welcome! There are lots and lots of examples on this site. For example, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156623/how-to-make-a-rotated-multiple-row-label-of-a-table-vertically-centered is a good place to start. If you get stuck, post the code you've got so far and let us know the specific problem you're having.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with this

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{ \multirow{2}{2cm}{\textbf{Elements} }  } & \textbf{percentage} & \textbf{Additional}\\ 
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{} & \textbf{(in \%)} & \textbf{Information} \\ \hline
 & & & & & \\
\multirow{24}{0.5cm}{\begin{sideways}Elements\end{sideways}}&\multirow{21}{0.5cm}{\begin{sideways}Non-metals\end{sideways}}&\multirow{6}{0.5cm}[3 mm]{\begin{sideways}Nonbio\end{sideways}}&E1.1& 1 &  \\ 
 & & & & & \\ \cline{4-6}
 & & & & & \\ 
 &  & &E1.2& 2 & \\  
 & & & & & \\ \cline{3-6}
 & & & & & \\
 &  &\multirow{13}{0.5cm}{\begin{sideways}Biodegradable\end{sideways}} &E1.3& 3 & \\ 
 & & & & & \\ \cline{4-6}
 & & & & & \\
 &  & &E1.4& 4 & \\ 
 & & & & & \\ \cline{4-6}
 & & & & & \\
 &  & &E1.5& 5 & \\ 
 & & & & & \\ \cline{4-6}
 & & & & & \\
 &  & &E1.6& 6 & \\ 
 & & & & & \\ \cline{4-6}
 & & & & & \\
 &  & &E1.7& 7 & \\ 
 & & & & & \\ \cline{2-6}
 & &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & &  \\
 & \begin{sideways}Metals\end{sideways} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Others} & 8 & \\ 
 & & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}  & & \\ \hline
 \end{tabular}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Maybe you have some problems if you add info in last column. Perhaps you can use another environment like `tabulary`, but with this environment I had problems.